# PHP7.2.3をPHP7.4へアップデートしたいのですが、# yum remove php php-*と打ったら、依存性関連での削除をしますphpMyAdminと表示されました

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

#### やりたいこと

CentOS7にインストールされているPHP7.2.3をPHP7.4へアップデートしたい

参考にしているページ

[PHP7.4へのアップデート](https://kz-style.com/arch/oss/server/php74.html)

#### 試したこと

```
# yum remove php php-*

//中略

依存性関連での削除をします:
 composer                             noarch     1.6.3-3.el7.remi            @remi           1.7 M
 phpMyAdmin                           noarch     4.7.9-1.el7.remi            @remi            24 M

//中略

上記の処理を行います。よろしいでしょうか？ [y/N]N
```

#### 質問

・yを押したら、インストールされているphpMyAdminも削除されるのですか？
・phpMyAdminを削除してもデータベースには影響ありませんか？ 現在はphpMyAdmin経由でMySQLへアクセスしています。
・依存性関連での削除(phpMyAdminの削除)をせずに、現在のPHPを削除する方法はありますか？　このやり方は非推奨ですか？
・PHPエクステンションもインストール`$ sudo yum -y install --enablerepo=remi --enablerepo=remi-php72` していたのですが、PHP7.4でも同じ処理が必要ですか？同じやり方でよいですか？　エクステンション内容がPHP本体に取り込まれているかどうか確認する方法はありますか？

Comment: 複数の質問が混在しているように見えます。 / 現状の php はどのリポジトリからインストールしたものですか？

Comment: 現状の php はremiリポジトリからインストールしました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yを押したら、インストールされているphpMyAdminも削除されるのですか？

その通りです。

> phpMyAdminを削除してもデータベースには影響ありませんか？

phpMyAdmin はあくまで (PHP 製な) MySQL のクライアントツールです。データベース自体には影響しないはずです。

> 依存性関連での削除(phpMyAdminの削除)をせずに

`yum` の代わりに `rpm` コマンドで `--nodeps` オプションを指定することで、依存関係を無視して対象のパッケージのみを削除すること自体は可能です。

```
# rpm -e --nodeps <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

composer や phpMyAdmin は PHP がインストールされていることが前提なので、依存関係で削除時に表示されています。